# Why is my file with 10 random bytes larger than 10 bytes?

Tags: string, openssl, random

So I have generated a random string of 10 bytes using the command `openssl rand -hex 10 > result`. My question is why does the resulting file have a size of 21 bytes? I haven't encrypted so I am not expecting padding in any form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man openssl` explains this in the `RAND` section:

> openssl rand [-base64] [-hex] [-out file] num
> The rand command outputs num pseudo-random bytes.

You specified 10 bytes, but asked they be expressed in hexadecimal (`-hex`).  Hexadecimal uses two characters, from `00` up to `ff` to express each byte's value.  Ten bytes means 20 hexadecimal characters, and the 21st character is the standard newline character that most programs output at the end of a line.